# custom constraint of weight matrix

Tags: python, keras

I want to invert a classifier on MNIST dataset on keras, thus the determinant of weight matrix must not be zero. Then I can use x=W-1f-1(y)

But there is no custom constraint in keras.

Comment: I think that this being a punctual contraint, it would be quite complicated to implement. And the answer provided by ibarrond sounds quite interesting.

Answer (score 1):

By far the easiest way to ensure that is to check wether the trained *W* has determinant 0. If it doesn't then you're OK to go, if it does you can add a small constant (`1e-7`) to any weight in the matrix and solve the issue. I can tell you anyway that the odds of zero determinant happenning are almost negligible.